# Unable to install Julia package

Tags: julia

I'm trying to instal the Escher web based UI package for [Julia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_(programming_language)). Following the instructions on the [Escher page](https://shashi.github.io/Escher.jl/), I've started the Julia REPL and entered:

```
julia> Pkg.add("Escher")
```

…but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: unknown package Escher
 in wait at task.jl:51
 in sync_end at /Applications/Julia-0.3.9.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:319
 in add at pkg/entry.jl:71
 in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:28
 in cd at /Applications/Julia-0.3.9.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in __cd#229__ at /Applications/Julia-0.3.9.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in add at pkg.jl:20
```

My Julia version is 0.3.9. I'm running it on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu and the package installed just fine, did you try Pkg.update() first and then installing?

Comment: I just installed it under Windows and 0.3.9 without problems.  (I just heard about it from the abstract on JuliaCon, looks pretty nifty).

Comment: Have you installed any other packages?  If not, what happens after using `Pkg.init()`?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Following @jfish003's suggestion I ran `Pkg.update()` and then tried the `add` – this worked. Seems like something where the error report could be better?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Pkg.update()` to make sure your METADATA is up to date.

Comment: Julia 0.3.9 is very old. Is Escher even available for Julia 0.3?

Comment: I thought the oldest versions were. It might be best just to flag this question for review as not being reproducible anymore.

Comment: I'm happy to delete if this is no longer relevant.

Comment: That would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you not installed before, you should init it 1st.

```
Pkg.init()
```

Then, if you want to update the already installed package,

```
Pkg.update()
```